# An environment for writing regular-font pseudocode

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, vertical-alignment

I want to create a pseudocode environment that looks like this:

[image: source cl.ly/3O2W203g3j1I3T080x37]

Basically, the font doesn't change - it's just the same as that of the surrounding text. It allows mathmode. And there is a box around it that fits the content vertically and horizontally (with some pre-defined margin), and then horizontally centers the entire box on the page.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `tabbing` environment, together with a personal environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{boxedcode}
 {\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\boxedcodebox}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
  \begin{tabbing}}
 {\end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}%
  \fbox{\usebox{\boxedcodebox}}}
\newsavebox{\boxedcodebox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{boxedcode}
Inputs: $s_{j}{k}$, \= $j=1,\dots,M-i$, $k=1,\dots,d$ as in \eqref{whatever}\\
                    \> and $h_1,\dots,h_M$ ($h_l=t_l-t_{l-1}$)\\[\baselineskip]
$A_\mathrm{prev}(k)\leftarrow 0$, $k=1,\dots,d$\\
for \= $j=1,\dots,M-i$\\
    \> $B_\mathrm{next}\leftarrow 0$\\
    \> for \= $k=1,\dots,d$\\
    \>     \> $A_\mathrm{next}(k)\leftarrow A_\mathrm{prev}(k)+s_j(k)*h_{i+j}$\\
    \>     \> $B_\mathrm{next}\leftarrow B_\mathrm{next}+A_\mathrm{next}(k)*A_\mathrm{next}(k)$\\
    \>     \> $A_\mathrm{prev}(k)\leftarrow A_\mathrm{next}(k)$\\
    \> end\\
    \> $m_j\leftarrow (B_\mathrm{next}-B_\mathrm{prev})/(2h_{i+j})$\\
    \> $B_\mathrm{prev}\leftarrow B_\mathrm{next}$\\
end\\
return $m_1,\dots,m_{M-i}$
\end{boxedcode}
\caption{Calculation of discrete drift parameters}\label{algo:drift}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Martin Scharrer points out, the code for the environment can be simplified by loading the `adjustbox` package:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newenvironment{boxedcode}
 {\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}%
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,fbox}
  \begin{tabbing}}
 {\end{tabbing}
  \end{adjustbox}}
```

This avoids the need to allocate a box bin.

---

Here is a version that allows page breaks (of course it shouldn't be set in a `figure` environment):

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newenvironment{boxedcode}
 {\setbox\boxedcodebox=\vbox\bgroup
  \begin{tabbing}}
 {\end{tabbing}\egroup
  \begin{mdframed}[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr(\textwidth-1em-\fboxrule-\wd\boxedcodebox)/2\relax,
    rightmargin=\dimexpr(\textwidth-1em-\fboxrule-\wd\boxedcodebox)/2\relax,
    innerleftmargin=1em,
    innerrightmargin=1em,
    innertopmargin=1em,
    innerbottommargin=1em,
    skipabove=\topsep,
  ]
  \vskip-\baselineskip\unvbox\boxedcodebox
  \end{mdframed}
 }
\newsavebox{\boxedcodebox}
\newlength{\boxedcodewd}
```

The environment should be always preceded and followed by blank lines and *not* put inside a `center` environment, because the centering is already taken care of by the set parameters.

If the class used is `book` the keys `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` should be replaced by `innermargin` and `outermargin`.

Please, keep the inner padding space.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The `minipage` will be as wide as the `tabbing` environment requires anyway, if it doesn't exceed `\textwidth`. If the `tabbing` lines are too long one will notice it anyway. But I'll modify the code.

Comment: egreg, @MarcoDaniel: An alternative would also be: ``\newenvironment{boxedcode}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,fbox,center}%
        \begin{tabbing}%
}{%
        \end{tabbing}%
    \end{adjustbox}
}
`` The `minipage` key can also be replaced by `varwidth`, but as egreg said, it isn't that important if the content is only a `tabbing` environment.

Comment: @MartinScharrer A `minipage` or `\parbox` containing *only* a `tabbing` environment won't be wider than necessary to enclose it. So `adjustbox` or `varwidth` are *not* necessary in this case.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, as I wrote I now that `varwidth` is not required in this specific case. `adjustbox` is just to simplify the code. You can of course box the content manually as you did in order to avoid an extra package, but other users might find it simpler.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I see, now.

Comment: Thanks, this works…almost. Is there any way to update this such that longer code can be split across pages? (Such that the vertical lines on both sides just continue from one page to the next (of course not going into the footer).)

Comment: @meh This is a rather different question. The package `mdframed` allows breaks in framed objects.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use mdframed with your solution? Your solution is absolutely wonderful, except that it doesn't support page breaks. With that added, everything would be absolutely perfect.

Comment: @meh I've added it.

Comment: Thanks, we're almost there! There are still two problems with this. To see them, turn all the inner margins to zero, as shown here: http://cl.ly/123m091T0w2y3d3g380W Next, here is an example usage: http://cl.ly/1O080S2E161R3o1Y162o Finally, here is the output: http://cl.ly/3j1l0I2N0Q47391f3T3W The first problem is that there is still an extra margin on the right side. The second problem is that there is a vertical margin after the box. Any ideas on how these problems can be fixed?

Comment: Well, just to make sure things look completely symmetric, given the provided margins.

Comment: This fixes the right margin. Thanks. However, are you sure about the spacing after the box? I've replicated this issue in a stripped down tex file: http://cl.ly/2C1s2s1c2c0V2f1M0K0d/texprob.tex And this is my output: http://cl.ly/000z193o2f2q2n2g2235

Comment: I still get an unwanted space after the last line in the box: http://cl.ly/0D0l1N3Z450I0S1K2S2X/texprob.tex

Comment: That's weird. This is my output: http://cl.ly/1L1k151M0R1W0243081Q I wonder why I get a different output than you do.

Comment: @egreg I've decided to just tweak things around (say by adding -1em if needed to some dimensions) to make this work for me. One final question: If the main font of the document is 11pt, do you know how I can make the font inside the box 10pt?

Comment: @meh Just add `\small` after `\bgroup`

Comment: @meh In case, some comments might be obsolete now or later, would you be so kind to remove them? Next time, the chat might be a good place to discuss a problem in depth, which could not be done in the question & answer way here.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need exotic control structures, you could also have a look at the algorithm package. It provides a set of statements that are aligned automatically. Some tweaking might me necessary, though. A stripped down version of your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Inputs:}}
\begin{document}
and each $A_\mathrm{next}(k)$ records a quantity of the form
\[
   \sum_{\ell=i}^j \hat{\sigma}(t_{i-1},t_\ell)h_{\ell+1}.
\]
\centerline{\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\begin{algorithmic}
   \REQUIRE $s_j(k), j=1,\ldots,M-i$ as in (3.101) and $h_1,\ldots,h_m$
   \STATE $A_\mathrm{prev}(k)\gets0,\, k=1,\ldots,d$
   \FOR{$j=1,\ldots,M-1$}
      \STATE $B_\mathrm{next}(k)\gets0$
      \FOR{$j=1,\ldots,d$}
      \STATE $A_\mathrm{prev}(k)\gets A_\mathrm{next}(k)$
      \ENDFOR
   \ENDFOR
   \RETURN $m_1,\ldots,m_{M-i}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, avoid `\centerline`.

Comment: The line break after `\fbox{` will add a space. You need to write `\fbox{%` or remove the line break in the source code. See my comment to @egreg's answer for a easy solution based on my `adjustbox` package.

Comment: It is also possible to use `\STATE`-only commands to remove any formatting, or modify the formatting altogether. Then there's also `algpseudocode` from the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `float` to create custom environments. See [wikibooks: custom floats](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Custom_Floats).

(1) Import package and create an environment, e.g. `pseudocode`:

```
\usepackage{float} % Import of the package.
 \floatstyle{boxed} % This creates the box around your environment.
 \newfloat{pseudocode}{htb}{lop}[chapter] % Placing and numbering.
 \floatname{pseudocode}{Pseudocode} % Name of the float displayed in the document.
```

(2) At the location where you need the figure, add your created environment:

```
\begin{pseudocode}
 \centering
   % add anything you want here ...
 \caption{My pseudocode!}
 \label{code:mycode}
\end{pseudocode}
```

**Updated** - the aligning is not trivial, indeed. You can use minipages surrounded by `\fbox` with borders.

```
\begin{center}
 \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[htb]{0.5\textwidth} % width 50%
    % add anything you want here ...
  \end{minipage}
 }
\end{center}
```

Comment: That doesn't horizontally fit the box to the content - it makes the box take up the entire horizontal page no matter how narrow the content is...

Comment: Also, how do I change the top,bottom,left,right inner margins (the distances between content and box)?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. However, the updated code fixes the width at 50%. It's not flexible according to the content.

Comment: You have some issues here: `\fbox{` will add a space, you need to write `\fbox{%` or remove the line break. The `minipage` argument `[htb]` looks wrong, it's either `t` or `b` etc. Also `center` should not be used inside floats. Use `\centering` instead.